# modsecurity allow 1 country only

Tags: mod-security2

I'm currently using the following modsecurity config on my webservers to block countries:

```
SecGeoLookupDb GeoIP.dat
SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "@geoLookup" "chain,id:1,deny,msg:'Block IN'"
SecRule GEO:COUNTRY_CODE "@streq IN"
```

Now for a new project I'm looking to allow only certain countries. Can this be done using a default rule that blocks all traffic and something like the following to allow a country?

```
SecGeoLookupDb GeoIP.dat
SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "@geoLookup" "chain,id:1,pass,msg:'Block IN'"
SecRule GEO:COUNTRY_CODE "@streq IN"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it could. Or you could just do it in one chained rule using something like this:

```
SecGeoLookupDb /usr/local/geo/data/GeoLiteCity.dat
...
SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "@geoLookup" "chain,id:22,drop,msg:'Non-GB IP address'"
SecRule GEO:COUNTRY_CODE "!@streq GB"
```

Which will only allow GB.

This example is taken from the documentation: https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#GEO

Or to allow multiple countries, try using the [@pm](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#pm) operator:

```
SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "@geoLookup" "chain,id:22,drop,msg:'Non-GB or IE IP address'"
SecRule GEO:COUNTRY_CODE "!@pm GB IE"
```

Comment: Thanks! And what if I would like to allow 2 or 3 countries?

Comment: Added an example for that